# Can I activate VR using the AF-on button instead of a shutter half-press on my Nikon DSLR?

Tags: nikon, image-stabilization, camera-controls

Usually I use the AF-on button on my Nikon D300 to focus when shooting sports. This way I can focus on the center, recompose, and be ready when something interesting happens.

When using a lens with VR I noticed that the VR system only kicks in when I press the shutter release button. Does this influence the reaction time in any way?

Comment: Found an article that explains a lot more about VR
http://www.bythom.com/nikon-vr.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure it affects the shutter lag, if that's what you mean by *reaction time*, but it will likely affect the efficiency of the VR system. If you want to use back button focus, you still need to half press the shutter button to activate the VR a couple of seconds or so before fully pressing the shutter button to take the picture. Otherwise the gyros won't be spinning at full speed and you might wind up causing the picture to be blurrier than without VR. Normally VR is not needed when shooting sports unless you are using a focal length longer than 1/Tv (Tv=shutter speed). There aren't many 1000mm lenses available that I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks, I'm talking about 70-200mm so that won't be a problem.